# Change Spotify's sound output device

Tags: windows, audio, spotify

Spotify does not have changeable sound output device, it uses the default device. But I want it to use Line1, a custom sound device I've added.

*Does anyone know how I can assign Line1 as output device*, right now my solution is setting the line1 as default but I still want my others programs to use my speakers.

Answer (score 6):

Some users contacted Spotify in an attempt to [get this changed](http://getsatisfaction.com/spotify/topics/get_spotify_play_another_audio_device_than_the_default_one), and got the following reply:

> Hey,
>
> Unfortunately Spotify does not offer an option to select a primary
>   audio output at this time. It should simply copy whatever you have set
>   for your computer's by default.
>
> I hope this is something we can add into a future release. For now
>   you'll just have to bear with us on this one.  Kind regards,
>
> Richard  Spotify Customer Service  http://www.spotify.com/help

Good news: People are working around it. There is a third party client called [Fidelify](http://www.fidelify.net/), which gives you the option to use a different output device, from what I have read.

> Fidelify uses Spotify Core to deliver streaming content in a bit
>   perfect stream directly to the soundcard, using either ASIO or WASAPI.
>   In addition the player itself is optimized for bufferless playback to
>   minimize jitter. Convolver DSP is integrated in the player to allow
>   real time FIR filter correction of the audio stream, and a custom VST
>   module to allow users running an additional DSP effect or EQ on the
>   audio stream.

[image]

Comment: Fidelify is only in Beta, and will only work for PREMIUM ACCOUNT holders.

Answer (score 0):

For all of the Mac users out there, the only way I could alter my Spotify output was to change the output device in my sound output settings under system preferences.  Of course, this affects everything, not just Spotify.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When searching for a Solution for this problem I found a built-in setting in the Spotify desktop client. For some reason it's not visible by default.

To make it visible, you need to launch Spotify with the parameter `--enable-audio-graph`.

You can accomplish this the easiest by creating a Desktop shortcut towards

```
%APPDATA%\Spotify\Spotify.exe --enable-audio-graph
```

given that you are using the default installation path.

You should be able to select the playback device in the "Playback" section, after clicking on "Show Advanced Settings" at the bottom of the preferences page (Ctrl + P)

Comment: This option is not valid any longer